# What would human characters eat in a world with no animals

Tags: food

I am developing a fictional world. There has been no animal life for 500 years. Assuming that humans were technologically advanced enough to keep the environment stable, what would they eat?

Comment: What do [vegans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veganism) eat?

Comment: Yeast-based foods like yoghurt, sauerkraut, & wine. Plants, algae, mushrooms and fungi. I assume insects and worms are also out, because they are animal life.

Comment: Aren't humans animals?

Comment: If there is no animal life at all (no insects, worms, etc.) you may run into a problem of sustaining higher plants. Can you specify the extent of lack of animals?

Comment: Surely this is a duplicate question? I remember a question about what one would eat on Mars to sustain life. Same concept.

Comment: They would eat, cakes .. of course.

Comment: you will need bacterial derived refined B12 supplements as there are no good plant sources. They will have to do this a with a few other vitamins as well,

Comment: Humans are animal life.... plus if you take out insects and sea life you have huge problems with your ecosystem in terms of making it livable for humans.

Comment: Agreed. Plants would grow out of control, including algae in water, and you would see a surge of oxygen in the atmosphere and wildfires would grow, metals and other materials would oxidize much more quickly. Besides humans being animals, you may want to change it to large fauna have died off or been hunted to extinction.

Comment: @a4android: Yogurt is made from milk, which is an animal product.

Comment: A problem with the vegan diet that people conveniently forget about is that the purely vegan diet is too low in protein for humans to grow on. In third world countries vegan diets work only because ofthe number of insect that are accidentally consumed with the vegetable matter. Even cattle get their proteins almost entirely from insects they accidentally consume.

Comment: @jamesqf Rodents! To think I thought I had carefully avoided dairy products in my comment and still managed to get it monumentally wrong. Thanks for torpedoing that error.

Comment: You're starting to look pretty tasty.....

Comment: @sphennings, LOL are you suggesting his human characters eat each other? That doesn't sound sustainable. LOL

Comment: @Len I'm suggesting that if there are no animals, the question is moot since there would be no humans.

Comment: @sphennings, well, sure, they all ate one another!

Comment: @pojo-guy I have never heard that claim before, and it does not sound reasonable. Do you have any sources for that belief, or is it your own hypothesis? And what about modern vegans eating washed vegetables in developed nations for years, are you suggesting they all have died or will soon die?

Answer (score 11):

## Vegetables

I don't really see any reason to close this question, but the answer is pretty trivial. What do you eat that isn't animals? Here is a [list of foods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_foods).

If you are more worried about the ecosystem effect of not having animals (such as pollinators), here is a list of [bee-pollinated edible plants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_crop_plants_pollinated_by_bees). There are some important foods on that list, but plenty of important plants that are not.

A full agricultural complex will have starchy staples, legumes, oil seeds, fiber plants, fruits (for vitamin C), and leafy greens. Examples in each category that are wind pollinated include:

- Starchy staples: Wheat, rice, corn and bananas.
- Legumes: Soybeans, lentil, pea, peanut
- Oils: Soybeans, peanut, oil palm, olive
- Fiber: Jute, hemp, raffia. Also, you can just replace cotton with nylon or polyester and skip the plants.
- Fruits: Banana, dates, heirloom tomatoes, pineapple
- Leafy greens: These will grow leaves without pollination; seeds can be produced from human pollinated hybrids.

So even without pollinators, you will be able to eat.

Comment: Peanuts would be a very large part of the diet. They have high protein which is the closest to meat protein on that list. 
Too bad sweet potatoes aren't included, they are almost identical to meat in terms of protein and would help keep people healthier.

Answer (score 4):

There is a long history of vegetarian / vegan lifestyles (ranging back to the former 7th centruy BCE https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegetarianism and the latter 1944 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veganism). There are indicating that not eating meat or any animal based foods is survivable -- perhaps even more "healthy."

We eat protein to rebuild and repair our bodies and if necessary act as fuel, though the fuel aspect is better served by carbohydrates. One thing to keep in mind is that protein (one of the main things you get from food outside fibre, vitamins/minerals) is made up of amino acids. Amino acids are essentially complex molecules, found in cells, with short lifetimes. When you stop eating a diverse of foods your body must remanufacture the amino acids or operate in a deficient manner (this is a tree top level discussion, for instance animal fat can be considered "high powered" fuel -- forgive the lack of references, I've worked professionally with biology types).

All of this being said, you can produce animal proteins artificially in a lab. This would suggest that it could be done on an industrial level. I can't find any examples of anyone pursuing this strategy (again wikipedia https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein).

Answer (score 1):

Soylent Green

They could be vegans, but you know the truth...

Edit:
Per Vincent's excellent comment below, not everyone has seen the movie Soylent Green (but you should fix that if you have not). The premise is that in a post-apocalyptic/Utopian future society people often opt to commit a form of assisted suicide where they are drugged into a state of euphoria before being put to sleep. Also, completely unrelated, everyone eats this super health food called Soylent Green.

Spoiler:

> Twist! in the words of Charlton Heston, "Soylent Green is people!!!!"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/43658)

Comment: @JohnWDailey Why to you think that this does not provide an answer to the question? In a world where humans have displaced every other animal species, the soylent green solution of feeding dead humans back to the ignorant masses actually seems pretty reasonable.

Comment: For those who haven't seen the movie, this is not an answer.

Comment: @Vincent Wait, you're telling me there are people that Haven't Seen Soylent Green?!? o_O

Comment: @MParm I haven't seen Soylent Green, though the plot synopsis did trickle all the way to me, and the meme is pretty ubiquitous.

Comment: I'm not sure of sustainable this is. How many humans a year does one human need to survive? Pretty sure this ends with a rapidly decreasing population until humans die out.

Comment: I would not be surprised. it's an old movie no? I saw it in a philosophy class (I think) , otherwise I would probably never have seen it.

Comment: @MParm: There are people (I'm one) who just don't like watching movies.  I'd much rather read the book - and IIRC, I did, though I understand the movie took a lot of liberties.

Comment: @Lio Elbammalf: You don't need to eat ONLY humans, just as for most of us meat forms only part of our diet.

Comment: Half Past Human, a novel by T.J. Bass has a similar theme

Answer (score 1):

Without non-human animals, plants would need a source of carbon dioxide.  When it comes to gases, plants are net oxygen producers.  Fungi, on the other hand, are net carbon dioxide producers, just as animals are. The elimination of animal life might create more niches for fungal life.

It's possible that humans could selectively breed the fungi for nutritional value. Fungal steak, anyone?